# How to add a action for addDOMListener of Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dom-events

I just want to load the Google Maps based on the Mouseover event of different div element. For doing this I just used the following simple code. This code itself not working, can someone tell me what mistake I have made?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.740, -74.18),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var content = '<strong>A info window!</strong><br/>That is bound to a marker';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: map.getCenter(),
      draggable: true
    });

    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener($("#showmap"), 'mouseover', function(){ alert("Hi");});
</script>


<div id='showmap'>
  Show Map
</div>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 400px"></div>
```

Above simple alert function itself not called for this simple code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector returns the jQuery object and the needed element can be accessed directly from the element array with a `[0]` . Also, make it "addDomListenerOnce", only need to initialize once.

```
$("#showmap")[0]
```

[**see a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/145/)

```
google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce($("#showmap")[0], 'mouseover', 
                                 function(){ initialize(); });
```

Comment: Thanks @MayAnne But a simple onclick event was also able to initialize the google maps. Just know tried and its working. Once again thanks for clarifying my doubt in the maps.event.addDomListener.

Comment: I'm surprised, I did try the addDomListener with a click listener but without the `[0]`, and the map does not appear.

Comment: I just used this one 
<div id='showmap' onclick="initialize(1.37422,103.945,'<h2>Tampines</h2>')">

It initialized the map with the infobox window. I just tried using an idea from javan can we try a method call from the onclick and check whether it is working and to my surprise it worked. Now my problem is solved very easily. I can geo tag an n number of places.

Comment: The part that needed to be changed relates to how we are getting the element from a jQuery selector. We can rewrite the addDomListener part like this: `google.maps.event.addDomListenerOnce(document.getElementById("showmap"), 'mouseover', function(){ initialize(); });` and it will work. To get the same element with jQuery we need to address that element array

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using this and this also worked.

**Java Script Code:**

```
  function initialize(lat,longit,content) {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longit),
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: content
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: map.getCenter(),
      draggable: false
    });

    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
```

**Html Code:**

```
 <div id='showmap' onclick="initialize(1.37422,103.945,'<h2>Tampines</h2>')">
  Show Map
</div>
```

I just tried using an idea from java, can we try a method call from the onclick and check whether it is working and to my surprise it worked.